# Who is the Elise that Beethoven composed about?

Tags: history, classical-music, beethoven

What is the history about the famous piano piece "Für Elise". Do we know who this lady that Beethoven immortalized was? Did he have a big, fat old crush on this lady? Was it a case of unrequited love? It very much sounds like she has a boyfriend if you listen to some of the brooding qualities of the piece.

What exactly is the history behind this piece?

Comment: Is there a tag for this kind of "what inspired the music" type of question?  If not, maybe there should be, but I can't think of a good term to use.  Adding "composition" might make sense, since you're trying to get at the what/how the composition came to be.

Comment: There is some Googlable information available.

Comment: He extremely prescient,  and wrote it for Eliza:  http://cyberpsych.org/eliza/#.WUJwMVUrLsA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia offers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCr_Elise) some possibilities:

> - Max Unger suggested that Ludwig Nohl may have transcribed the title incorrectly and **the original work may have been named "Für Therese"**, a
>     reference to **Therese Malfatti von Rohrenbach zu Dezza** (1792–1851). She
>     was a friend and student of Beethoven's to whom he supposedly proposed
>     in 1810, though she turned him down to marry the Austrian nobleman and
>     state official Wilhelm von Droßdik in 1816.
> - According to a 2010 study by Klaus Martin Kopitz (de), there is evidence that the piece was written for the German soprano singer
>     **Elisabeth Röckel** (1793–1883), later the wife of Johann Nepomuk Hummel.
>     "Elise", as she was called by a parish priest (she called herself
>     "Betty" too), had been a friend of Beethoven's since 1808.
> - In 2014, the Canadian musicologist Rita Steblin suggested that **Juliane Katharine Elisabet Barensfeld** (de), who used "Elise" as a
>     variant first name, might be the dedicatee. Born in Regensburg and
>     treated for a while as a child prodigy, she first travelled on concert
>     tours with Beethoven's friend Johann Nepomuk Mälzel, also from
>     Regensburg, and then lived with him for some time in Vienna, where she
>     received singing lessons from Antonio Salieri. Steblin argues that
>     Beethoven dedicated this work to the 13-year-old Elise Barensfeld as a
>     favour to Therese Malfatti who lived opposite Mälzel's and
>     Barensfeld's residence and who might have given her piano lessons.

See also [forelise.com/about](http://www.forelise.com/about).

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QCUTafCK9s